# value on select tag HTML convert array to string Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using Javascript with Angular Js, In my controller I have the following Items :

```
$scope.address = [];
$scope.states = [
    { name:"State 1", cities:[ "City Mexico 1", "City Mexico 2","City Mexico 3"] },
    { name:"State 2", cities:["City  1", "City  2", "City  3"] }
  ];
```

In my view I am doing :

```
<select ng-model="address.state" placeholder="Estado" >
            <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state}}"> {{state.name}}</option>
          </select>
```

If I select an option, and then I do console.log(address.state) I get the object as an String instead of as array. How can I get the object as array (json).

The console output look like this :

```
[state: "{"name":"State 1","cities":["City Mexico 1","City Mexico 2","City Mexico 3"]}"]
```

I want to get the object as array, because then I do $Scope.address.state.city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing an `ng-repeat` on the `<option>` tag you can do `ng-options` in the `<select>` tag:

```
<select ng-model="address.state" ng-options="state.name for state in states" placeholder="Estados"></select>
```

That way the object of state is passed into `$scope.address` and you can do `$scope.address.state.cities`

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/k2gK5GNEt2xTrMbwih7V?p=preview

Comment: When you're passing in as `value="{{state}}"` you're making that object into a string due to the "{{ ... }}" and with `ng-options` you are passing the actual object